# Yandex map Запретить автоматическое изменение центра карты при перетаскивании маркера

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При перетаскивании маркера к краю карты происходит автоматическое изменение центра карты. Можно ли отключить данное поведение? Спасибо!

Comment: Почему вы хотите его отключить, чем оно мешает?

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент это поведение неотключаемое.